# Cells are not populating in second collection view inside of table

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview, multiple-instances

I am new to coding and I am losing my mind with my current problem. I have a table view controller with 7 cells. I have 4 collection views in 7 of the cells. I have labels in the other three. I am trying to get my first two collection views to work so I can attack the same approach to add the other two. I am currently only able to get the cells of my first collection view (in cell 2) two populate. I don't know how to get the cells of the second collection view to populate.

Here is the code for the table view controller:

```
import UIKit

class HomeTableViewController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var t10MacInfCollectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var t10MicroInfCollectionView: UICollectionView!

let T10Mac = "T10Mac"

let T10Mic = "T10Mic"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    t10MacInfCollectionView.delegate = self
    t10MicroInfCollectionView.delegate = self

    t10MacInfCollectionView.dataSource = self
    t10MicroInfCollectionView.dataSource = self

    self.view.addSubview(t10MicroInfCollectionView)
    self.view.addSubview(t10MicroInfCollectionView)

    t10MacInfCollectionView.reloadData()
    t10MicroInfCollectionView.reloadData()

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    if collectionView == self.t10MacInfCollectionView {
        
        return 10
        
        }

        return 10
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    if collectionView == self.t10MacInfCollectionView {
        
        let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: T10Mac , for: indexPath) as! T10MacroCollectionViewCell
        
        return cellA
        
        }

    else {

        let cellB = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: T10Mic , for: indexPath) as! T10MicroCollectionViewCell

        return cellB
            
        }

    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    if collectionView == self.t10MacInfCollectionView {
        
        return CGSize(width: 125.0, height: 225.0)
        
           }
    
    else {

            return CGSize(width: 125.0, height: 225.0)
        
               }
    }

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 7
    }
}
```

I am literally so frustrated. If someone could please help, I will be so thankful. Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: At quick glance I immediately see one small typo that seems to have big consequences.  At the point where you add the collectionViews as subview you are adding the same one twice instead of adding each one once.

Comment: Creeperspeak! Thank you so much. I changed that and it ended up deleting some of my cells. I ended up removing the addSubview and it fixed my problem. Thank you for helping me get the ball rolling for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

In the viewDidLoad() func: delete

```
self.view.addSubview(t10MicroInfCollectionView)
self.view.addSubview(t10MicroInfCollectionView)
```

The viewDid should now look like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

t10MacInfCollectionView.delegate = self
t10MicroInfCollectionView.delegate = self

t10MacInfCollectionView.dataSource = self
t10MicroInfCollectionView.dataSource = self

t10MacInfCollectionView.reloadData()
t10MicroInfCollectionView.reloadData()

}
```